# Numerical stability in the product of many matrices

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have to calculate in numpy the product of many matrices (~400). Are there common practices to increase numerical stability?

If this is relevant, the matrices are `300x300` orthogonal projection matrices.

Thanks!

Comment: Matrix product or element-wise?  `np.linalg.multi_dot` performs a series of matrix multiplications.  It talks about an optimization, but I think that has more to do with the sizes of the arrays than numeric stability.  And in your case the matrices all have the same shape.  You might need to look at more theoretical math sources or forums.

Comment: thanks, I'm talking about matrix product.